# WPF DataGrid Coloring - Custom Coloring For Both Rows and Cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid control that uses custom coloring for both the data rows and individual data cells.  Some rows need to be colored, but there are also some individual cells that need to show a specific color regardless of their row's background color.  I am handling the coloring like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
            <!--Row Coloring-->
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInactive}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <!--Cell Coloring-->
            <local:ColorConverter_RunToday x:Key="converter_RunToday"/>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.Header}" Value="Run Today">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource converter_RunToday}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource converter_RunToday}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

My color converter class is:

```
public class ColorConverter_RunToday : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value.ToString().Trim().ToUpper();

        if (str == "YES")
            return Brushes.LightGreen;

        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The only problem with this setup is that the "Run Today" cell with the custom coloring will never have the background color of the row.  Setting the color to Brushes.Transparent still just colors the cell white if the cell's text is not "YES".  In addition, when I have that row selected the custom cell does not get the normal blue highlight color.

I have previously gotten a solution to work by individually coloring each cell programmatically instead of using XAML, but it would not display correctly when scrolling unless I disabled row virtualization on the grid.  This would cause it to perform terribly on a grid containing a lot of data.

Comment: Why cell coloured Green will show Gray? Doesn't that what you want? Also please post snaphsot what it's like and how you want it to be.

Comment: If the background is colored gray, but the "Run Today" cell is "Yes", I want the entire row to be gray but that one cell to be green.  Otherwise, I want the entire row to be gray, including the "Run Today" cell.  Right now, the "Run Today" cell will always be either green or white, never gray.

Comment: I tried your code in sample. First point is working completely fine at my end. Can you try it out in small sample to see if problem lies somewhere in another code. If it still persist try to post the sample code here so that we can help.

Comment: So when you row gets selected you want the green cell to become blue and also your gray cell to become blue? Which one is not working?

Comment: You're right, there was something else going on in my solution that was causing that issue with the background color staying white. However, I still have an issue with the coloring of these cells when the row is selected.  The custom cell never gets highlighted in blue when its row is selected.  It does, however, change the foreground text.  This causes the text to go invisible when you select a row with a "Run Today" of "No", since the background stays white.  See [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a7jRFgz).  I can upload my sample project too if you'd like.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue in sample code. Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25327280/632337).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are only interested in drawing cell to LightGreen for following conditions:

1. Column name is Run Today.
2. Cell text is Yes.
3. Cell is not selected.

But, with converter in place you end up setting background for cells which doesn't satisfy above conditions *(to Transparent)* resulting in some issues. Might be overriding default values for dataGrid, so try to avoid that.

I would suggest to achieve this with **`MultiDataTrigger`** and provide above 3 conditions there. *(No need for converter)*

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.Header}" Value="Run Today"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text}" Value="Yes"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGreen"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: That did it!  I just didn't have any way of checking whether the row was selected with my previous solution, but that MultiDataTrigger can handle it.  Thanks again!